# C# ListView Display

Tags: c#

Guys i'm a beginner in implementing ListView in c#. I'm having a problem with these piece of code in c#.net. And I can't figure out whats happening in the control shown by the output. It seems i forgot something to give a value in properties of ListView Control.

2nd column values must appear on the first column.

[image]

This is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;   
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;                  
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;        
using System.Data.OleDb;            
namespace Database2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        OleDbConnection con;
        OleDbDataAdapter adapter;
        DataTable table;

        string conString = "Provider = Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0.; Data Source=DatabaseTest.mdb";
        string sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM Person";

        public Form1() {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e){
            con = new OleDbConnection(conString);
            adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(sqlQuery,conString);
            table = new DataTable();

            InitializeList();

            adapter.Fill(table);

            for (int i = 0; i < table.Columns.Count; i++)
                lstDisplay.Columns.Add(table.Columns[i].ColumnName.ToString(), lstDisplay.Width / 6-1);

            for (int i = 0; i < table.Rows.Count; i++) { 
                ListViewItem row = new ListViewItem();
               for (int j = 0; j < table.Columns.Count; j++)
                    row.SubItems.Add(table.Rows[i][j].ToString());
               lstDisplay.Items.Add(row);
            }
        }

        private void InitializeList() {
            lstDisplay.GridLines = true;
            lstDisplay.AllowColumnReorder = true;
            lstDisplay.LabelEdit = true;
            lstDisplay.FullRowSelect = true;
            lstDisplay.Sorting = SortOrder.Ascending;
            lstDisplay.View = View.Details;
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a listView property i forgot to give a value?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `ListViewItem` itself represents the first column. Subsequent columns are represented by `ListViewSubItem`s.

Ex:

```
for (int i = 0; i < table.Rows.Count; i++)
{ 
   ListViewItem row = new ListViewItem(table.Rows[i][0].ToString());
   for (int j = 1; j < table.Columns.Count; j++)
      row.SubItems.Add(table.Rows[i][j].ToString());
   lstDisplay.Items.Add(row);
}
```

Comment: wow Thank you very much. That was a quick answer to my problem. I need to wait 4 minutes before I can accept your answer. :-D Up

Answer (score 2):

from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listviewitem.listviewsubitem.aspx):

> A ListView control displays a list of items that are defined by the ListViewItem class. Each ListViewItem can store subitem objects that are defined by the ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem class.

[`ListView.Items`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.items.aspx) represents first column and [`ListViewItem.SubItems`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listviewitem.subitems.aspx) represent sub item for each rows. So that your code should be like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < table.Rows.Count; i++)
{ 
   ListViewItem row = new ListViewItem(table.Rows[i][0].ToString());
   for (int j = 1; j < table.Columns.Count; j++)
   {
      row.SubItems.Add(table.Rows[i][j].ToString());
   }
   lstDisplay.Items.Add(row);
}
```