# C# - SQlite + Entity - Show items on a ListView

Tags: c#, listview

Using Visual Studio 2015 and learning ORM with SQlite + Entity (WPF application)

My database with fields: ID and ShipType

I can populate a listView with the ShypType field:

```
    private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        List<string> shipList = new List<string>();
        using (var db = new ImperialFleetDBEntities())
        {
            shipList = (from g in db.ShipsType select g.ShipType).ToList();
            db.Dispose();
        }

        listView.Items.Clear();                   
        foreach (string str in shipList)
        {
            listView.Items.Add(str);
        }

    }
```

**But I can't figure how to also diplay the ID field (g.ID on this example)**

In this link [C# ListView Display](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11698485/c-sharp-listview-display) the solution is using ListViewSubItems

But If I type listView. I don't have any SubItems option

The solution is 5 years old, maybe that's de problem??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way would probably be:

```
private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    using (var db = new ImperialFleetDBEntities())
    {
        listView.Items.Clear();
        foreach(var item in (from g in db.ShipsType select new { ID = g.ID, ShipType = g.ShipType }))
        {
            listView.Items.Add(item)
        }
    }
}
```

This should populate your listView in correct way and make sure these new objects won't be tracked by EF.

If you'd like, you could create full class, like ViewModel for listView containing fields you need and then select to them like:

```
foreach(var item in (from g in db.ShipsType select new NewShipType { ID = g.ID, ShipType = g.ShipType }))
{
    listView.Items.Add(item)
}
```

or using constructor (if you make one).

With seprate ViewModel you can of course use in-between list object and clear and add them to listView.Items, which is impossible with anonymous object.

By the way, you don't have, and maybe you shouldn't write `db.Dispose()` inside `using` clause, as `using` is exactly meant to make sure the object inside is disposed - you cannot use `using` on object that is not implementing `IDisposable` interface.

Comment: With the first solution I get 

(field) ListView MainWindows.listView
Property or indexer 'ItemsControl.Items' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only

Comment: I'm sorry, to be honest I didn't check it because I don't have compiler nearby and I forgot it doesn't work like that in WinForms, as I haven't used them for some time. Please take a look at edit. Of course there is other version (with in-between list), that should work without any problem.

Comment: I'm sorry too, is a WPF application not a Windows Form. The edited solution removed the compilation error but didn´t showed up anything on the control

Comment: Solved thanks to "If you'd like, you could create full class, like ViewModel for listView containing fields you need and then select to them like:"